# need advice for creating game AI -> javascript

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a pacman game in javascript to learn the language, and the most elements of it are done nicely except of.... the 4 ghosts AI. Right now I am using a pretty basic approach (like searching for x and y and try to get closer to pacman, if the ghosts hits a wall or other ghost e tries to unstuck himself by going into a random direction until it hits another wall or ghost). The thing is, this approach is just not good at all, most of the times ghosts get stuck between them for some time, or go to very erratic directions.
What I want to ask is, what could be an approach for constructing this AI considering this is javascript? I am not asking for already done code here, just some ideas to get me unstuck on this.

PS: I've thought of graphs and Disjktra et all, but, considering that the game is in a matrix and calculating 4 graphs + path every 250ms can be a lot costy....

Comment: Perhaps you can calculate each ghost's path every 4th cycle - this way each ghost's path path be update every second?

Comment: Sounds interesting, i'll look into it! Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior) is a very thorough introduction into specifically Pac-Man AI. It's very well written and I thoroughly recommend it.

For general pathfinding have a look at [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: Awesome link! Ill give it a good look and see if I can understand it. Many thx